# Intent Passing SkuDetails

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase

I would like to pass my selected Subscription Package to the next activity page. The class object is SkuDetails

What extension do I have to apply to do so ?

```
    val intent = Intent(this, SignUpActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("selected_plan" , selectedSkuDetails)
            startActivity(intent)
```

SkuDetails:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails

Comment: This may not be the optimal solution but can't you just create a new data class with same fields as SkuDetails? Then you can copy the contents of the original SkuDetails object to your new parcalable object and pass that with intent

Comment: Yes I agree with @Prethia

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your POJO class by `Serializable` because you cannot send an object to another class you have to make it into bytes or streams to send to another class and `Serializable` class do it for you. Here is an Example.

```
    //This object needs to send to activity
    data class WeatherResponse(
        @SerializedName("cod")
        val cod: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("count")
        val count: Int? = null,
        @SerializedName("message")
        val message: String? = null
    ) : Serializable

    //For sending Serializable Object to Activity
    val weatherResponse = WeatherResponse("Demo",1,"Hi Deummy")
    val intent = Intent(this, SignUpActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("weather_response" , weatherResponse)
    startActivity(intent)

    //for receiving Serializable Object into Activity
    var weatherResponse = intent.getSerializableExtra("weather_response") as WeatherResponse
```

Comment: While this answer is right, in Android it is a better idea to extend your data classes with Parcelable rather than Serializable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Serializable is slower than Parcelable and not recommended in good practices.